# Virtual hosts on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, virtualhost

I have a domain `test.mydomain.com`. I put it into the browser address bar and I get into the Tomcat control panel.

The application is deployed on the tomcat and at the address `localhost/test/` it starts. The application is deployed in the local folder `webapps/test`

Now I want that when accessing the host, `test.mydomain.com` is redirected to my application. I added to server.xml in the `<Engine>` section

```xml
<Host name="test.mydomain.com"  appBase="webapps/test"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.test.mydomain.com</Alias>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="test_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.base}/webapps/test"
   debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

I got access to my application, with the exception of two servlets

```java
@WebServlet(name = "Options", urlPatterns = "/js/options.js")
public class Options extends HttpServlet {

@WebServlet(name = "AggregateIconController", urlPatterns = "/images/points/agg.svg")
public class AggregateIconController extends HttpServlet {
```

In the `web.xml` file, I have defined such rules

```xml
<web-app version="3.1"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">
  <display-name>Test Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Those connection points is a subset of the masks defined in web.xml.

When accessing the address `test.mydomain.com/js/options.js` I get an error 404. But when accessing`localhost/test/js/options.js` the page returns.

When adding rule to `web.xml`

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Options</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/js/options.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything worked for me. What did you do

1. Took out applications for this host in a separate folder, which is located outside of `${catalina.base}/webapps` this is stated in [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/TomcatDevelopmentVirtualHosts) of Tomcat

   > In order to create virtual hosts, do the following:
   >
   > 1. Create a separate directory for each host **outside of $CATALINA_HOME/webapps**
   > 2. Underneath each directory, create a webapps directory.
2. In `server.xml` left only lines

   ```xml
   <Host name="test.mydomain.com"  appBase="test/webapps"
           unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
     <Alias>www.test.mydomain.com</Alias>
     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
            prefix="test_access_log" suffix=".txt"
            pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
   </Host>
   ```
3. Renamed the original war to `ROOT.war` and put it in the `test/webapps` folder. Tomcat himself deployed it in `test/webapps/ROOT`
4. I did not understand about servlets. For

   ```java
   @WebServlet(name = "Options", urlPatterns = "/js/options.js")
   public class Options extends HttpServlet {
   ```

   explicitly wrote in `web.xml`

   ```xml
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Options</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/js/options.js</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

   (before this, this approach still did not work).

   For

   ```java
   @WebServlet(name = "AggregateIconController", urlPatterns = "/images/points/agg.svg")
   public class AggregateIconController extends HttpServlet {
   ```

   everything worked independently